# subject vs assign in rails specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am reading the code someone else have written, 
I have noticed that he uses capybara create on the features test,

```
client = create :client
```

assign on the view specs

```
assign :client, build(:client)
```

What is the diference between those 2 ?

Comment: Are you sure that :client is from Capybara?  It looks more like FactoryGirl being used to generate the data.

Answer (score 0):

[**assign(key, val)**](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#assignkey-val)

Use this to assign values to instance variables in the view:

```
assign(:widget, Widget.new)
render
```

The code above assigns Widget.new to the @widget variable in the view, and then renders the view.

Note that because view specs mix in ActionView::TestCase behavior, any instance variables you set will be transparently propagated into your views (similar to how instance variables you set in controller actions are made available in views). For example:

```
@widget = Widget.new
render # @widget is available inside the view
```

---

**subject** that is your variable in rspec.

[RSpec Subject](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-3/docs/subject/explicit-subject)

```
RSpec.describe Array, "with some elements" do
  subject { [1, 2, 3] }

  it "has the prescribed elements" do
    expect(subject).to eq([1, 2, 3])
  end
end
```

Comment: Just FYI: David Chelimsky cautions that this explicit use of subject may be a spec-smell: http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/blog/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/   The RSpec Subject doc is less severe but recommends using a named subject instead.